# php sitemap for large websites

Tags: php, sitemap, large-data

I want to create a sitemap for a page with more than 30.000.000 pages. The page is daily updating, removing and adding new pages.

I found this php script which I would like to run with a cron job.

[Sitemap php script](http://www.php-ease.com/classes/sitemap.html)

I have all URIs in the table "myuri" in the column "uri" entries are written e.g.  "/this-is-a-page.html". What parameters do I need to add to the script to get it running on my table?

```
<?php

/*
 *    author:       Kyle Gadd
 *    documentation:    http://www.php-ease.com/classes/sitemap.html
 *
 *    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *    (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *    GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

class Sitemap {

  private $compress;
  private $page = 'index';
  private $index = 1;
  private $count = 1;
  private $urls = array();

  public function __construct ($compress=true) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '75M'); // 50M required per tests
    $this->compress = ($compress) ? '.gz' : '';
  }

  public function page ($name) {
    $this->save();
    $this->page = $name;
    $this->index = 1;
  }

  public function url ($url, $lastmod='', $changefreq='', $priority='') {
    $url = htmlspecialchars(BASE_URL . $url);
    $lastmod = (!empty($lastmod)) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($lastmod)) : false;
    $changefreq = (!empty($changefreq) && in_array(strtolower($changefreq), array('always', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly', 'yearly', 'never'))) ? strtolower($changefreq) : false;
    $priority = (!empty($priority) && is_numeric($priority) && abs($priority) <= 1) ? round(abs($priority), 1) : false;
    if (!$lastmod && !$changefreq && !$priority) {
      $this->urls[] = $url;
    } else {
      $url = array('loc'=>$url);
      if ($lastmod !== false) $url['lastmod'] = $lastmod;
      if ($changefreq !== false) $url['changefreq'] = $changefreq;
      if ($priority !== false) $url['priority'] = ($priority < 1) ? $priority : '1.0';
      $this->urls[] = $url;
    }
    if ($this->count == 50000) {
      $this->save();
    } else {
      $this->count++;
    }
  }

  public function close() {
    $this->save();
    $this->ping_search_engines();
  }

  private function save () {
    if (empty($this->urls)) return;
    $file = "sitemap-{$this->page}-{$this->index}.xml{$this->compress}";
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . "\n";
    foreach ($this->urls as $url) {
      $xml .= '  <url>' . "\n";
      if (is_array($url)) {
        foreach ($url as $key => $value) $xml .= "    <{$key}>{$value}</{$key}>\n";
      } else {
        $xml .= "    <loc>{$url}</loc>\n";
      }
      $xml .= '  </url>' . "\n";
    }
    $xml .= '</urlset>' . "\n";
    $this->urls = array();
    if (!empty($this->compress)) $xml = gzencode($xml, 9);
    $fp = fopen(BASE_URI . $file, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $xml);
    fclose($fp);
    $this->index++;
    $this->count = 1;
    $num = $this->index; // should have already been incremented
    while (file_exists(BASE_URI . "sitemap-{$this->page}-{$num}.xml{$this->compress}")) {
      unlink(BASE_URI . "sitemap-{$this->page}-{$num}.xml{$this->compress}");
      $num++;
    }
    $this->index($file);
  }

  private function index ($file) {
    $sitemaps = array();
    $index = "sitemap-index.xml{$this->compress}";
    if (file_exists(BASE_URI . $index)) {
      $xml = (!empty($this->compress)) ? gzfile(BASE_URI . $index) : file(BASE_URI . $index);
      $tags = $this->xml_tag(implode('', $xml), array('sitemap'));
      foreach ($tags as $xml) {
        $loc = str_replace(BASE_URL, '', $this->xml_tag($xml, 'loc'));
        $lastmod = $this->xml_tag($xml, 'lastmod');
        $lastmod = ($lastmod) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($lastmod)) : date('Y-m-d');
        if (file_exists(BASE_URI . $loc)) $sitemaps[$loc] = $lastmod;
      }
    }
    $sitemaps[$file] = date('Y-m-d');
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . "\n";
    foreach ($sitemaps as $loc => $lastmod) {
      $xml .= '  <sitemap>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '    <loc>' . BASE_URL . $loc . '</loc>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '    <lastmod>' . $lastmod . '</lastmod>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '  </sitemap>' . "\n";
    }
    $xml .= '</sitemapindex>' . "\n";
    if (!empty($this->compress)) $xml = gzencode($xml, 9);
    $fp = fopen(BASE_URI . $index, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $xml);
    fclose($fp);
  }

  private function xml_tag ($xml, $tag, &$end='') {
    if (is_array($tag)) {
      $tags = array();
      while ($value = $this->xml_tag($xml, $tag[0], $end)) {
        $tags[] = $value;
        $xml = substr($xml, $end);
      }
      return $tags;
    }
    $pos = strpos($xml, "<{$tag}>");
    if ($pos === false) return false;
    $start = strpos($xml, '>', $pos) + 1;
    $length = strpos($xml, "</{$tag}>", $start) - $start;
    $end = strpos($xml, '>', $start + $length) + 1;
    return ($end !== false) ? substr($xml, $start, $length) : false;
  }

  public function ping_search_engines () {
    $sitemap = BASE_URL . 'sitemap-index.xml' . $this->compress;
    $engines = array();
    $engines['www.google.com'] = '/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=' . urlencode($sitemap);
    $engines['www.bing.com'] = '/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=' . urlencode($sitemap);
    $engines['submissions.ask.com'] = '/ping?sitemap=' . urlencode($sitemap);
    foreach ($engines as $host => $path) {
      if ($fp = fsockopen($host, 80)) {
        $send = "HEAD $path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $send .= "HOST: $host\r\n";
        $send .= "CONNECTION: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $send);
        $http_response = fgets($fp, 128);
        fclose($fp);
        list($response, $code) = explode (' ', $http_response);
        if ($code != 200) trigger_error ("{$host} ping was unsuccessful.<br />Code: {$code}<br />Response: {$response}");
      }
    }
  }

  public function __destruct () {
    $this->save();
  }

}

?>
```

There is already an example of usage on the page:

```
<?php

require_once ('php/classes/Sitemap.php');

$sitemap = new Sitemap;

if (get('pages')) {
  $sitemap->page('pages');
  $result = db_query ("SELECT url, created FROM pages"); // 20 pages
  while (list($url, $created) = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $sitemap->url($url, $created, 'yearly');
  }
}

if (get('posts')) {
  $sitemap->page('posts');
  $result = db_query ("SELECT url, updated FROM posts"); // 70,000 posts
  while (list($url, $updated) = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $sitemap->url($url, $updated, 'monthly');
  }
}

$sitemap->close();
unset ($sitemap);

function get ($name) {
  return (isset($_GET['update']) && strpos($_GET['update'], $name) !== false) ? true : false;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change this part....

```
if (get('pages')) {
$sitemap->page('pages');
 $result = db_query ("SELECT uri FROM myuri"); 
 while (list($url) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
 $sitemap->url($url,'', 'yearly');
  }
 }
```

Not sure if that `$updated` is needed?  Looks like the function just defaults it to an empty string anyways...... But maybe you could at a timestamp column to your table to pull the last updated date as well, and feed it into the function where I put ''.

Also....remove this part...

```
if (get('posts')) {
$sitemap->page('posts');
 $result = db_query ("SELECT url, updated FROM posts"); // 70,000 posts
 while (list($url, $updated) = $result->fetch_row()) {
$sitemap->url($url, $updated, 'monthly');
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so far its not wokring yet so I created a new post with the current state

Comment: Change this...while (list($url, $created) = $result->fetch_row())  to this...while (list($url, $created) =mysql_fetch_row($result))